# How to create feature columns for TensorFlow classifier

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tflearn

I have a very simple dataset for binary classification in csv file which looks like this:

```
"feature1","feature2","label"
1,0,1
0,1,0
...
```

where the `"label"` column indicates class (1 is positive, 0 is negative). The number of features is actually pretty big but it doesn't matter for that question.

Here is how I read the data:

```py
train = pandas.read_csv(TRAINING_FILE)
y_train, X_train = train['label'], train[['feature1', 'feature2']].fillna(0)

test = pandas.read_csv(TEST_FILE)
y_test, X_test = test['label'], test[['feature1', 'feature2']].fillna(0)
```

I want to run `tensorflow.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier` and `tensorflow.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier` on that data. For instance, I initialize DNN like this:

```py
classifier = DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[3, 5, 3],
                               n_classes=2,
                               feature_columns=feature_columns, # ???
                               activation_fn=nn.relu,
                               enable_centered_bias=False,
                               model_dir=MODEL_DIR_DNN)
```

So how exactly should I create the `feature_columns` when all the features are also binary (0 or 1 are the only possible values)?

Here is the model training:

```py
classifier.fit(X_train.values,
                   y_train.values,
                   batch_size=dnn_batch_size,
                   steps=dnn_steps)
```

The solution with replacing `fit()` parameters with the input function would also be great.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using TensorFlow version 1.0.1

Comment: unrelated to your question: you're filling missing values with `0` which I dont think would be appropriate given `0` is very meaningful in your dataset - its a ground truth label/class, and its a possible feature value. Which means whenever you're filling na, you're actually creating false training examples and assigning them to your negative (`0`) class

Comment: @Simon thanks for your comment! I realized that too. But I had done some feature engineering and I'm sure there are no missing values in the dataset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can directly use [tf.feature_column.numeric_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/feature_columns#numeric_column) :

```
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key = key) for key in X_train.columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just found the solution and it's pretty simple:

```
feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X_train)
```

Apparently `infer_real_valued_columns_from_input()` works well with categorical variables.