# Tensorflow : Creating a loop for feature variables

Tags: tensorflow

I have multiple feature columns in TensorFlow and I am trying to create the loop to avoid manual typing to create feature column but its not working. Below is the list of all the columns which I need to create feature columns(this is just a dummy data, but what if we have hundreds of columns).

```
num_preg = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Number_pregnant')
glucose_conc = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('glucose_concentration')
blood_prs = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('blood_pressure')
Tricep = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Triceps')
insulin = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Insulin')

I created a loop for this as mentioned below, df_col_num is a list containing the column names for which I need to create feature column.

for col in df_col_num:
    col= tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(col,hash_bucke[enter link description here][1]t_size=50)
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834680/creating-many-feature-columns-in-tensorflow/47384981#47384981. Basically if you can load your data through pandas (also you can apply filters too), you iterate through all columns, adding each to the list of features, without the need to declare each of them explicitly.

Comment: glad to hear. :D

Answer (score 3):

your variables are numeric, but you are using `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket`, which is for categorical variables.

I'd use:

```
variable_names = df.columns

tf_variables =[]

for index in variable_names:
    tf_variables.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(index))
```

This worked for me.